# Android - Google analytics INSTALL_REFERRER not firing

Tags: android, google-analytics, install-referrer

I'm trying to track my campaigns on google analytics, I've followed the tutorial but it is not working :( This is my manifest:

```
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When I try to test this and I send this command through the console it does nothing:

```
$ shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

The only thing I see is that if I send it twice it says:

```
Ignoring duplicate install campaign
```

So I guess that the app receives the intent, apart from that, the app wakes when i send the intent.

The tutorial says that the app will log (if it is correct)

```
GAv4    : Received installation campaign: source=testSource
```

And if there is any problem:

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

But in my case it says nothing :(

Can anybody please help me??? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: I'm also facing the exact problem. Did you get any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting of your device, FORCE STOP the app and clear its data. Try again, it will work. The broadcast expect a fresh app install which is not run.

Answer (score 1):

Before sending the broadcast, you need to enable debugging:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
```

Otherwise you will not see the message "Received installation campaign".

Answer (score 0):

Your app must not be running. Just install the app but do not run it. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLx-7AgN1Jw at exactly [14:00]

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall app, if it is already installed. Then follow below steps.

1. Install app using adb

   `adb install yourapp.apk`
2. To enable [debug logging](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#logger) on a device run:

   `adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG`

   `adb logcat -s GAv4`
3. Start broad casting

   `adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "com.example.gatestapp/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"`